# cors for express what exactly does it do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express server setup like so:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:8000'}));
// Parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(express.json());
// Parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


require('./app/routes/auth.routes')(app);
require('./app/routes/user.routes')(app);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on http://loclalhost:${port}`));
```

I am confused by what `cors` does, I am following a tutorial. Does it only allow requests coming from `http://localhost:8000`?

Comment: Just read the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) for `cors()` or the [wiki article on CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or [this CORS article from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CORS` comes from "[Cross-Origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)" and is, basically, a protocol that allows or not a server to acess your website resources (routes data, api requests etc).
When you use the `cors` module in Javascript and provide it the `origin` argument as `http://localhost:8000` it means that the domain `localhost` can acess your backend resources and get data from it while other domains can't. If, for example, the domain `stackoverflow.com` tried to scrape data from your server it would be blocked the `cors` module.
Cors is often used to avoid webscraping and malicious requests from another domains.
If you host your app on the heroku server for example, you would need to change the origin argument to your heroku app url.

Comment: Fantastic that's the explanation I was looking for. thanks!

Comment: @Kex Which is (more or less) the same explanation as in the wiki article...